# How to delete irrevelant sentence from Richtextbox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, nmea

I use GPS data and NMEA sentences.Even I only want to see and save the sentences which begins with "$GNGGA" and "$GNTVG" in my richtextbox, there are other sentences(lines) begining with different codes($GNGLL, $GLGSV, $GPGSV etc). What should I do to only get "$GNGGA" and "$GNTVG" sentences to Richtextbox?

Here is my code;

```
       string[] gParca;
    string gKG, gDB, gUydular, gYukseklik, gEnlem, gBoylam, gYataySapma, gKilitlenme, gVelocity, gSaat;

       private void GPSVelocity(string NMEA2)
    {
        gParca = NMEA2.Split(new char[] { ',' });
       switch(gParca[0])
       {
           case "$GNVTG":
               gVelocity = gParca[7];
               break;
       }
      private void GPSDataBilgisi(string NMEA)
    {
        gParca=NMEA.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        switch (gParca[0])
        {
            //Global Positioning System Fix data
            case "$GNGGA":
                gParca[2] = gParca[2].Replace('.', ',');
                gParca[4] = gParca[4].Replace('.', ',');
       }
      }
      private void serialPortGPS_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       GPSDataBilgisi(serialPortGPS.ReadLine());
       GPSVelocity(serialPortGPS.ReadLine());
    }   

    private void GPSVel(string NMEA2)
    {
       if(checkBoxSave.Checked)
       {
           richTextBoxGPSData.AppendText(NMEA2);

      }

    }

    private void GPSData(string NMEA)
    {
        if(checkBoxSave.Checked)
        {
            richTextBoxGPSData.AppendText(NMEA);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For my answer, can I assume `serialPortGPS` works like a `TextReader` object with its `ReadLine()` function? I would expect the data to come out of the event args but your code seems to think otherwise...

Comment: Yes, you can assume serialPortGPS as a TextReader .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Disclaimer**
>   As per OP's reply to my question, I am assuming `serialPortGPS.ReadLine()` works exactly like `TextReader.ReadLine()`.

Since you want to filter the input you are getting, add a filter to the function that retrieves the data.

```
private void serialPortGPS_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
       string line = serialPortGPS.ReadLine();

       if(line.StartsWith("$GNGGA"))
           GPSDataBilgisi(line);

       if(line.StartsWith("$GNVTG"))
           GPSVelocity(line);
   }
}
```

If the line starts with anything else (e.g. "HELLOIAMALINE"), neither if-check will pass and the code will not do anything with the line, it just moves on to the next one.

You can remove the `switch` statements in your code, they are no longer needed (of course keep the logic that is inside them!)

There are some caveats here, because I think your code and intention is a bit vague. If you can clarify any of these, I can update my answer.

- Going by your question, I assume you do not want to call `ReadLine()` exactly twice (once for each method). I infer that you want to read every line individually (because that's how `TextReader` usually works), check if it starts with a "good" value, and then execute the function that needs it.

My original example specifically reads 2 rows and parses them. If you are instead trying to read *all* lines from the gps update, change the code as follows:

```
 private void serialPortGPS_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   string line;
   while((line = serialPortGPS.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       if(line.StartsWith("$GNGGA"))
           GPSDataBilgisi(line);

       if(line.StartsWith("$GNVTG"))
           GPSVelocity(line);
   }
}
```

- Part of me wonders if reading directly from `serialPortGPS` is the correct approach. This is pure speculation, but I would expect your `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e` to contain a property with the newly received data. It's not impossible that what you are currently doing is correct, but it is more unusual than using the event args that you receive from the update event.
- You could use LINQ to immediately filter out the rows that you need (instead of having to manually iterate over them). However, `Textreader` implements a pattern where it only processes one line at a time (similar to `yield return`). If you use LINQ, you're going to end up processing all lines at the same time when you want to filter them. If you **need** to process line by line (e.g. because the data you're processing has a huge memory footprint), then you should avoid LINQ

If you want an example of LINQ:

```
List<string> theLinesThatIWant =
    allTheLines.Where(line => line.StartsWith("$GNGGA")).ToList()
```

But like I said, only use this if you are able and willing to have all the data in memory at the same time.